# How to detect custom object using EmguCV

Tags: c#, python, opencv, tensorflow, emgucv

I'm working on some object detection code. So, I've made a training and got .pb and graph.pbtxt files from tensorflow. The next thing that I've done, was python code, which performs my object detection based on these 2 files, using opencv for Python.
Here is my python script, which works well:

```
import cv2 as cv

cvNet = cv.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'graph.pbtxt')

img = cv.imread('75.png')
rows = img.shape[0]
cols = img.shape[1]
cvNet.setInput(cv.dnn.blobFromImage(img, size=(300, 300), swapRB=True, crop=False))
cvOut = cvNet.forward()
print(rows)
print(cols)

for detection in cvOut[0,0,:,:]:
    print(type(cvOut[0,0,:,:]))
    score = float(detection[2])
    if score > 0.1:
        left = detection[3] * cols
        top = detection[4] * rows
        right = detection[5] * cols
        bottom = detection[6] * rows
        cv.rectangle(img, (int(left), int(top)), (int(right), int(bottom)), (0, 0, 255), thickness=2)
        print('true')
    print(score)

cv.imshow('img', cv.resize(img, None, fx=0.3, fy=0.3))
cv.waitKey()
```

However, I need the same code, done with .NET (C#), using EmguCV library, which is a wrapper of conventional OpenCV.

Here is a part of code, that I've managed to write:

```
private bool RecognizeCO(string fileName)
{
            Image<Bgr, byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(fileName);

            int cols = img.Width;

            int rows = img.Height;

            imageBox2.Image = img;

            Net netcfg = DnnInvoke.ReadNetFromTensorflow("CO.pb", "graph.pbtxt");

            netcfg.SetInput(DnnInvoke.BlobFromImage(img));

            Mat mat = netcfg.Forward();

            return false;
}
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea what to do after that.... Actually, I nedd the same result in this C# code, like in Python one. I know, that I can just to call python scripts from C#, but I really need this code to be done in C# with EmguCV.
Please, help me!
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I've managed to end up that code...
the solution was quite easy:
after getting `mat` variable, we can just get `Data` from `Mat` as an float[,,,] array: `float[,,,] flt = (float[,,,])mat.GetData();`
or just use one-dimensional array: `float[] flt = (float[])mat.GetData(jagged:false)` (but I prefer the previous one)

Than, just make a loop threw that array:

```
                for (int x = 0; x < flt.GetLength(2); x++)
                {
                    if (flt[0, 0, x, 2] > 0.1)
                    {
                        int left = Convert.ToInt32(flt[0, 0, x, 3] * cols);
                        int top = Convert.ToInt32(flt[0, 0, x, 4] * rows);
                        int right = Convert.ToInt32(flt[0, 0, x, 5] * cols);
                        int bottom = Convert.ToInt32(flt[0, 0, x, 6] * rows);

                        image1.Draw(new Rectangle(left, top, right - left, bottom - top), new Bgr(0, 0, 255), 2);
                    }
                }
```

And finally, we can save that image:

```
image1.Save("testing-1.png");
```

So, the result code wil look like:

```
            using (Image<Bgr, byte> image1 = new Image<Bgr, byte>("testing.png"))
            {
                int interception = 0;

                int cols = image1.Width;

                int rows = image1.Height;

                Net netcfg = DnnInvoke.ReadNetFromTensorflow(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\fldr\CO.pb", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\fldr\graph.pbtxt");

                netcfg.SetInput(DnnInvoke.BlobFromImage(image1.Mat, 1, new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300), default(MCvScalar), true, false));

                Mat mat = netcfg.Forward();

                float[,,,] flt = (float[,,,])mat.GetData();

                for (int x = 0; x < flt.GetLength(2); x++)
                {
                    if (flt[0, 0, x, 2] > 0.1)
                    {
                        int left = Convert.ToInt32(flt[0, 0, x, 3] * cols);
                        int top = Convert.ToInt32(flt[0, 0, x, 4] * rows);
                        int right = Convert.ToInt32(flt[0, 0, x, 5] * cols);
                        int bottom = Convert.ToInt32(flt[0, 0, x, 6] * rows);

                        image1.Draw(new Rectangle(left, top, right - left, bottom - top), new Bgr(0, 0, 255), 2);
                    }
                }

                image1.Save("testing-1.png");
            }
```